# Fluent nhibernate many to one inverse returning error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Ive been googling this for a while now trying to understand nHibernate so I can solve it on my own but have come up short.  So I come from Entity Framework v1 in which we would write a select statement such as:

```
from query in context.Users.Include("Orders") where query.UserId == id select query;
```

Or something similar where you would get the result, say its a local variable called FoundUsers and if I wanted to load a reference, an Extension method was written to load the reference if it wasn't loaded:

```
FoundUsers.Orders.LoadIfNotLoaded()
```

then we can access FoundUsers.Orders.  With that said so you can get a visualization of my previous mindset, here is my current Fluent NHibernate setup:

```
public class Clan
{
    public virtual int Clan_Id { get; set; }
    [Simple properties]
    public virtual IList<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}


public class Match
{
    public virtual int Match_Id { get; set; }
    [Simple properties]
    public virtual Clan Clan { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the mapping files:

```
public class ClanMap : ClassMap<Clan>
{
    public ClanMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Clan_Id).Column("Clan_Id").Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Matches).Table("Matches").KeyColumn("Clan_Id").LazyLoad();
        Table("Clans");
    }
}

public class MatchMap : ClassMap<Match>
{
    public MatchMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Match_Id).Column("Match_Id").Not.Nullable();
        [simple properties]
        References(x => x.Clan).Column("Clan_Id").LazyLoad();
        Table("Matches");
    }
}
```

Here is my query statement:

```
public static Clan FindClanByName(string name)
    {
        ISessionFactory mySessionFactory = DatabaseUtilities.GetSessionFactory();
        using (ISession mySession = mySessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (mySession.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var find = mySession.QueryOver<Clan>().Where(t => t.Clan_Name == name).List<Clan>();
                mySession.Transaction.Commit();

                if (find != null && find.Count == 1)
                    return (Clan)find[0];
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I go and access the return 'Clan's Match List, I get the following error:

```
{"Initializing[Counter.Strike.Database.Clan#1]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: MyDatabase.Clan.Matches, no session or session was closed"}    NHibernate.HibernateException {NHibernate.LazyInitializationException}
```

I must have tried several different ways of doing the mapping and none have worked.  Some have given me this error and some have just returned a single (the first) record (there are 6 records in the database that should be returned).  I want to be able to access the list of Matches associated with the Clan, then the list of MatchStats associated with each Match (not detailed in this post but I'm sure I can figure out if I have a push in the right direction with this resolution).  Thanks!!

UPDATE 1:
I added a constructor in the Clan class to initialize the IList and changed my mappings to:

```
HasMany(x => x.Matches).Inverse().Cascade.All();

References(x => x.Clan);
```

I also changed my findclanbyname function around to be like so:

```
var find = mySession.QueryOver<Clan>().Where(t => t.Clan_Name == name).List<Clan>();
mySession.Transaction.Commit();

if (find != null && find.Count == 1)
    return find[0];
else
    return null;
```

As I'm stepping through the FindClanByName method, I can see the loaded matches when I set a breakpoint and watch the 'find' variable.  Once the method returns to the calling function, I lose the references to Matches and I get the error stated above.  Any ideas?

UPDATE 2: Just wanted to say that the nHibernate project is in a different project/namespace than the calling function.  I'm creating a wrapper around nHibernate.

UPDATE 3: I think this may be because I am leaving the visibility of the using statements.  Any idea on how to maintain the references outside of the session?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems like the main thing you are missing in your translation of Entity Framework knowledge to NHibernate knowledge is what the "session" corresponds to.

*EF's `DbContext` is roughly the same idea as NH's `Session`.*

I don't use EF much, but I imagine if you disposed the `DbContext` before you called `LoadProperty`, you would get a similar error, like:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

So, how did you used to manage DbContext life cycles in your Entity Framework projects?  You should probably do something similar in this NHibernate project.  For example, with a web application, you usually want something like a single NHibernate Session per web request.  You can open the session on the BeginRequest event, store it in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection, and then dispose of the Session in the EndRequest event.

---

Your second issue - only getting back a single record when you expect six - would this not be caused by `return (Clan)find[0]`?

Comment: With that project, the database access functions were a bit too integrated into the backend but I think they should have been more incorporated into the database api.  So we would open a context in the code behind, request the data via the context, then any references were loaded.  Unfortunately if we decided to change database/API, the whole project would have to have be rewritten.  I don't want to do that with this project.  If I don't keep nHibernate, I want as minimal changes to the project as possible.